# Reading mysqli prepared statement into array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, fetch

My understanding of mysqli prepared statements and result sets is that they are all stored server side meaning you can only have one available at once. This is a pain when you are trying to use the results of the first query to loop through and enact a second query.

My code tried to read in the first result set so it can be looped through and read.

```
$sql = 'SELECT VISIT_ID, UPRN, VISIT_REF, VISIT_DATE, START_TIME, END_TIME, NOTES,  REALNAME from V_PREVIOUS_VISITS where UPRN = ?';

/* Prepare statement */
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
if($stmt === false) {
    trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $db->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

$VisitArray = array();
$stmt->bind_param('i',$_GET['UPRN']);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetch();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $VisitArray[]= $row;
};

$stmt->free_result();

foreach($VisitArray as $Visititem){
?>
Visit Ref:<?=$Visititem['VISIT_REF']?><br/>
Visit Date:<?=$Visititem['VISIT_DATE']?><br/>
Conducted by:<?=$Visititem['REALNAME']?><br/>
Notes:<?=$Visititem['NOTES']?><br/>
Rates:<br/>
    <?
     }
    ?>
```

I am now confused between the mysqli_stmt class and the mysqli_result class and how I can use the array method from the result class against something that has been called in the statement class.
I appreciate that this is down to my lack of knowledge of classes in coding - sorry.

Comment: +1 for the proper error handling alone. Such a relief to see trigger_error once in a while among all these dies

Comment: you can try get_result(). if it isn't avaliable, you have to stick to that ugly bind_result()

Comment: It would seem that: `$result = $stmt->get_result(); ` does the trick -thanks. So it would appear that get_result will create a mysqli_result class then???

Answer (score 0):

Just for sake of getting answered.

You can try get_result(). If it isn't available, you have to stick to that ugly bind_result(), combining it with get_result_metadata() and nd such. There are many example codes on the bind_result's manual page.